# Custom memcmp() of a struct with char member

Tags: c, memory, memcmp

I've written the following C code to compare two areas of memory and check if they are identical

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s1 {

   int a, b;
   char c;

} s1;


int memcmpwannabe(void* value1, void *value2, int size1, int size2) {

   if(size1 != size2)
      return -1;

   if(size1 == 0 || size2 == 0)
      return -1;

   //memcmp() wannabe
   char *p1 = value1;
   char *p2 = value2;
   int sz = size1;

   do {
       if(*p1 != *p2)
           break;
       else
           p1++, p2++;
   }
   while(--sz != 0);

   if(sz == 0)
      return 0;

   return -1;

}


int main() {

   struct s1 v1;
   struct s1 v2;

   v1.a = 1;
   v1.b = 2;
   v1.c = 'a';

   v2.a = 1;
   v2.b = 2;
   v2.c = 'a';

   int res = memcmpwannabe((void*) &v1, (void*) &v2, sizeof(s1), sizeof(s1));

   printf("Res: %d\n", res);

}
```

The structures are identical, but it will return -1 anyway.
After some debugging i found that the 3 padding bytes after the char variable
are filled with random data, not with zeroes as i was expecting.

Knowing this and the fact that i want to keep it as generic as possible (so using void* as arguments), can somebody point me to an alternative byte to byte comparison?

(Before somebody asks, i'm writing a custom memcmp() because in some implementations [it will continue after a difference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/14/10075623.aspx)

Comment: There will be padding after the c structure member. Containing (more or less) random values. These can compare unequal to other random bytes.

Comment: Can you modify the structure members to *include* the padding? Then you can set them to a known value -- i.e., 0 or any other constant.

Comment: Why do you consider two 0-length-ranges different?

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, that is something related to the program i'm writing, just ignore it.

Comment: Does `memset(&s1, 0, sizeof(s1));` after the declaration of both variables helps?

Comment: @AlterMann: Even if it would, that's at best a band-aid which is not really reliable.

Comment: setting the whole struct to a known value, immediately after declaration of any instance would work for making comparisons.  Otherwise, the comparison would need to be field by field.  Then the comparison would only work for the specific struct definition.  Then, memcmp() would work and the posted code would not be needed

Comment: Note: Functional differences between `memcmpwannabe()` and `memcmp()`.  1) `size`: `int` v. `size_t`, 2) when `size == 0`, returns -1 v. 0 for `memcmp()` 3) On difference: `memcmpwannabe()` only returns -1, `memcmp()` returns + or - values to indicate _order_.  4) `memcmpwannabe()` is UB if `size < 0`, not applicable to `memcmp()`

Comment: @chux 1) yes, i think it would be better with size_t

2/3) design choice, it hasn't to emulate the original memcmp()

4) you got a point

Comment: @user3629249 do you mean doing a memset() like Alter Mann wrote?

Comment: Some thoughts: If `memcmpwannabe()` does not have to emulate the original `memcmp()` then "writing a custom memcmp() because in some implementations it will continue after a difference" does not apply - after all, this is then a _different_ function.  So either the function is like `memcmp()` aside from the "continue after a difference" issue and should mimic `memcpy()` functionality as able, or it isn't.  If the latter case, recommend that it receive a more distinctive name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Knowing this and the fact that i want to keep it as generic as
>   possible (**so using void* as arguments**)

If you only take `void *` pointers, by definition you know nothing about the internal organization of the objects. Which means you know nothing about the meaning of the bytes (which are in "real" members and which are in hidden, padding-only members).

I would say this is not something that you can easily do with standard C.

Comment: @pattern23 I don't know. C++ may have some fancy way to get the type of the pointed-to object (I don't think RTTI covers that?) but I am only speculating.

Comment: Let's say i find a fancy way to discover the pointed type. Then, how can i write a generic function that iterates through the members and compare them one by one?

Comment: @pattern23 In that case you probably need more magic: something like annotations left over by the compiler for debuggers' use.